# Android Dynamic Table, Last two rows not displaying

Tags: android, sqlite, android-tablelayout

I have a table which rows I created dynamically with data from SQLite.
Currently, I have just 30 records in the table, but when I generate the rows with the data at hand, I saw only 28 rows, the other 2 are missing. I confirmed from my Log cat that I have 30 records.

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Table Body-->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Method that retrieves data returned as list from SQLite.

```
public List<RosterItem> fetchRoster(){
        List<RosterItem> rosterList = new ArrayList<>();
        String readQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + RosterTable.NAME;


        try{
            mDatabase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            mDatabase.beginTransaction();

            Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(readQuery, null);
            //Looping through each row and adding to list
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    RosterItem rosterItem = new RosterItem();
                    rosterItem.setSyncNumber(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(RosterTable.Cols.SYNC_NUMBER)));
                    rosterItem.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RosterTable.Cols.DATE)));
                    rosterItem.setShift(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RosterTable.Cols.SHIFT)));

                    //Add to list
                    rosterList.add(rosterItem);

                }while(cursor.moveToNext());

                cursor.close();
            }
            mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally {
           mDatabase.endTransaction();

        }
        mDatabase.close();

        return rosterList;
    }
```

Fragment where data is used.

```
List<RosterItem> allRosters = dbAdapter.fetchRoster(); // Check for possibility of empty array b4

Log.d(TAG, "Number of items " + allRosters.size());

for(RosterItem roster: allRosters){
    Log.d(TAG, "" +roster.getSyncNumber());

    //Generate contents of table (Table Body)
    int rosterNumber = roster.getSyncNumber();
    String rosterDate = roster.getDate();
    String rosterShift = roster.getShift();

    //Generate table rows
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
    //Set parameters
    TableRow.LayoutParams tabParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tabParams.setMargins(2,2,2,2);
    row.setLayoutParams(tabParams); //Necessary in order to be able to set the margins

    String[] colText = {rosterNumber+"", rosterDate, rosterShift};
    for(String text:colText){
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(16);
        tv.setPadding(5,5,5,5);

        tv.setText(text);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setLayoutParams(tabParams);
        row.addView(tv);

    }
    mTableBody.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    mTableBody.addView(row);

}
```

Screenshot shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEsW8.png)

Comment: Why didn't you try for ListView or Recycler View?

Comment: Yh...I want it to look tabular with all the border lines and cells. I can't figure out how I will be able to achieve that with a recyclerView.

Comment: you could just setup border in row layout of recyclerView. With your current approach, views are not being recycled. Every time new view is getting created. As data grows it may lead to crashes.

Comment: But with the issue of data grows and app crashing, the data in that fragment will never exceed the 30 records.

Comment: Ooh, I saw the problem. The issue is that I have three tabs each with a fragment. The first fragment I used recyclerview with cards to markup its data.The other fragment, the above one, I used a tableLayout.  When the App loads and I did not scroll through the contents of the first fragment, is then that the above fragment will be misbehaving by not loading all the data. But If I first visit the first fragment and scroll through the data, when I return to the above fragment, things work well. What might be causing this?